# Javascript For Loop With Decimal Increments Has A Wrong output

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have a problem which I think is a bug. So I have created a for loop:

```
var multi=2;
 for (limit=0; limit < length; limit += 1.2) {
      multi++;
 }
 console.log(multi);
```

The output is correct for all range of values except for the instance where length=10.8 or any multiples thereof. The output shows as multi=12 which in fact it should be 11.

Can somebody tell me why is this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: welcome to the wonderful world of [floating point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Also named as IEEE754 pitfalls. In some domains it is simply forbidden to use float as an incrementable variable to avoid absorption/cancellation.

Comment: Try to compute `(float_max_value) - 0.001`

Comment: You can try something like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb1ua0ur/1/) to fix it.

Comment: Thank you Rajesh! I was actually trying to do something like this but had trouble with what syntax to use. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
var multi=2;
 for (limit=0; limit < 10.8; limit += 1.2) {
      multi++;console.log(limit +"-"+multi);
 }
 console.log(multi);
```

output is

> 0-3
>
> 1.2-4
>
> 2.4-5
>
> 3.5999999999999996-6
>
> 4.8-7
>
> 6-8
>
> 7.2-9
>
> 8.4-10
>
> 9.6-11
>
> 10.799999999999999-12 // yes here it should be 10.8

So final multi will be 12 . 
10.79 is less than 10.8 so multi will be increase

Comment: This is not the required answer. As per your output `9.6 + 1.2` should yield `10.8` but it yields `10.7999...`. Why?

Comment: oh yeah , edited

Answer (score 0):

because multi values is 2

```js
var length = 10.8
var multi  = 1;
 for(limit = 0; limit<length; limit+=1.2) {
      multi++;
 }

console.log(multi); // 11
```

you can change limit+=1.2 to limit+=1.3 for getting 11

```js
var length = 10.8
var multi  = 2;
 for(limit = 0; limit<length; limit+=1.3) {
      multi++;
 }

console.log(multi); // 11
```

Comment: Its not about fixing loop. Question is **why `9.6 + 1.2` yields 10.79999** and not `10.8`. That is already answer in the link shared by Nina

Comment: because 9.6 + 1.2 = 10.799999999999999

Comment: that should also be the result with any language that implements IEEE floating point